# Animação Parallax e Fade para web

Tags: jquery, css, css3, parallax

Realizei todos os movimentos [desta URL](http://eduardosully.com/tropico) no Muse e Edge Animate da Adobe, mas quero fazer na unha, codificando. Alguma dica de Parallax ou animações parecidas no Codepen ou Github?

Quero realizar o efeito de Stop Scrolling.

Preciso animar o meu scroll até certo ponto, chegando nesse ponto, preciso que essa div pare de rolar. Preciso que as minha `DIVs` fiquem paradas após um certo X de scroll. No [plugin scrolld](http://scrolldjs.com/) a animação do scroll é por meio de clique, o qual não terei.

Como faço?

Comment: Eu achei essa solução. Funciona para o que quero?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858994/let-user-scrolling-stop-jquery-animation-of-scrolltop

Comment: Acredito que essa não é a solução que você procura. Dê uma olhada na minha resposta abaixo e veja se não é mais prática de implementar.

Answer (score 2):

**Uma boa opção é usar o plugin Scrolld.js para JQuery. Ele permite fazer scrolling com extrema precisão.**

http://scrolldjs.com/

Veja que a demo2 trata de funções que irão te interessar, como scrollDistance.

Ele permite uma série de animações com scroll e é uma biblioteca pequena de ser carregada na página.

**Na prática, o que deve ser feito é monitorar a posição do scroll na página e iniciar as animações em javascript quando determinado ponto for alcançado.**

Você precisa definir uma série de Event Listeners e quando o trigger for acionado, solicitar ao javascript que altere a CSS dinamicamente.

Por exemplo, o primeiro efeito de sobrepor os itens é facilmente alcançado mudando o z-index da div inferior, no CSS, para um número mais positivo do que o da div anterior, mudando sua posição absoluta em x pixels à cada scroll down.

O último efeito também é simples, trata-se de duas divs também com z-index mais positivo do que os demais elementos, que são animados de posições fora da página para posições dentro da página. Por exemplo, a div da esquerda é animada de left: -200px até left: 200px *- valores hipotéticos -* (de fora da tela para dentro da tela em 200px).

Animar com JQuery é fácil, basta selecionar a div e mudar a propriedade:

```
$("mydiv").css("z-index","2")
```

O código acima muda o z-index da mydiv para +2 (colocando ele em planos acima das divs com z-index menor do que 2).

**Segue também uma função para criar o Event Listener do scroll down. Ela diz se o scroll dado é para cima ou para baixo. Basta criar um contador de scrolls (para baixo adiciona 1, para cima diminui 1) e atrelar as demais animações à contagem desse contador.**

*Lembre que no contador você precisa criar uma restrição onde ele não poderá ser negativo (já que o usuário não pode dar scroll para cima do começo da página) e não poderá ser mais positivo do que o número de scrolls para chegarmos ao fim da página (já que o usuário pode dar diversos scrolls no fim da página e não queremos que isso afete a contagem).*

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        console.log('Scroll up');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Scroll down');
    }
});
```

**Agradeço ao cilphex pela função que monitora o scroll down: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201159/cilphex**

Boa Sorte.

Comment: Muito obrigado Punch! :)

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo esse [parallax 1](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/07/how-to-create-a-simple-parallax-effect/)  para começar ele é mais simples e via te dar idéia central de como funciona . Só passe para o proximo quando tiver 101% de certeza do que está acontecendo no código.

[Parallax 2](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/10/24/creating-a-parallax-scrolling-webpage-using-jarallax-js/) esse tem uma explicação maior.

- Update link Parallax 2

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia
o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter 
conteúdo aqui mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta;  
você poderia fazer isso?
Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! 
Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: 
[Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)

Comment: Olá @Bruno Rozendo, o segundo link [Parallax 2](http://www.webdesignshock.com/one-page-website/) não existe mais, tem algum outro?

Abraços.

Comment: já fiz o update.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer a div parar de "andar" é só capturar a distancia dela em relação ao topo e colocar um limite, se chegar a esse limite ela para, no caso pode ser colocado um position: fixed.

Você pode capturar a distancia dela com a função .offset() do jQuery, depois usar  $(window).bind('scroll') com um if para comparar.